# PHP: try-catch-finally in loop with continue in catch

Tags: loops, try-catch, php-7, continue, try-catch-finally

Ok, just a technical question about the code above:

```php
foreach($x as $y){ // or even a simple for()
    try{
        a();
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        // just skip current iteration
        continue;
    } finally {
        c();
    }
}
```

Since `c()` is in the `finally` block it should be always executed, but what about the `continue` statement?
According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) it appears to be making the `finally` block being skipped.

So, does `c()` be executed in case of `a()` throwing an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple to discover just using console. Type

```
php -r 'foreach([1, 2] as $n){try {echo "\n", $n, "\n"; throw new \Exception();} catch (\Exception $e) {continue;} finally {echo "finally has been called";}}'
```

which is single-string representation of the code

```
foreach ([1, 2] as $n) {
    try {
        echo "\n", $n, "\n";
        throw new \Exception();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        continue;
    } finally {
        echo "finally has been called";
    }
}
```

you'll get

```
1
finally has been called
2
finally has been called
```